# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

**Ты же хочешь() как лучше?**

Answer (score 1):

Я бы не ставила запятую. Слово как здесь вводит устойчивое сочетание. У Розенталя, правда, точно такого в списке нет,но много похожих: *приходить когда вздумается; спрятались кто куда успел; не лезть куда не следует; ночевать где придётся; бери что нравится; спасайся кто может; живите как знаете; здесь всегда можно достать что понадобится; всё было как положено; расскажите что вздумается; бери что дают; говорите как есть на самом деле; ругается на чём свет стоит; найду что делать; найду чем заняться; приглашу к себе кого пожелаю* и другие.

Comment: Согласен с таким ответом, но без условного наклонения. Запятая здесь действительно не нужна.